# Grid system not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So, I am trying to have these 4 images on two rows (on mobile only), two per row. On desktop, they are centered in one row only.

I can't make the bottom two centred on mobile, without messing up the desktop view.

**This is what I have:**

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
      <img src="assets/about/about1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
      <img src="assets/about/about2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
      <img src="assets/about/about3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
      <img src="assets/about/about4.jpg">
    </div>                  
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is what happens:** [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye9Uw.png)

Thanks

Comment: Use an offset ?

Comment: you can simply work with this. I am using bootstrap. the css I have there only does this padding: 0 1rem 1rem 0;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<div class="col-1 col-sm-1"></div>` you can use `offset-1` as more elegant solution.

Check out this code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 offset-1 offset-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
           <p>first</p>
            <img src="assets/about/about1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
            <p>second</p>
            <img src="assets/about/about2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 offset-1 offset-sm-0 aboutMid aboutMid1">
            <p>third</p>
            <img src="assets/about/about3.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
            <p>fourth</p>
            <img src="assets/about/about4.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [margin utils](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering) to center like this...

https://www.codeply.com/go/sA5gd0e2Zp

```
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 ml-auto aboutMid aboutMid1">
                <img src="//placehold.it/400" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 mr-auto mr-sm-0 aboutMid aboutMid1">
                <img src="//placehold.it/400" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 ml-auto ml-sm-0 aboutMid aboutMid1">
                <img src="//placehold.it/400" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 mr-auto mrnone aboutMid aboutMid1">
                <img src="//placehold.it/400" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you're welcome. If this answer worked you should mark it as accepted by clicking the checkbox to the left of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5 offset-1 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
            <img src="assets/about/about1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
            <img src="assets/about/about2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 offset-1 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
            <img src="assets/about/about3.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
            <img src="assets/about/about4.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What you are missing is second indentation on bottom row. You will need to fix this on larger screen by adding media query for that view size. example: `col-lg-5` with `offset-lg-1` maybe. However on mobile this will work try it

Comment: Oh, you missed my point. On desktop I want it to be 1 row with all 4 lined up

Comment: @GridTradg did you try it yet?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is bootstrap

col- with no suffix is for the smallest screens, I assume the mobile uses this range.

You have 12 cols per row, you now insert 1 + 5 + 5 + 5, which is why it looks wrong. You should insert the remaining cols so you have 12. (col- is now 24 cols in total, which is fine because you make 2 rows of 12 on mobile)

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
      <img src="assets/about/about1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
      <img src="assets/about/about2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
      <img src="assets/about/about3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
      <img src="assets/about/about4.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Or offset will also work as other answers say. Depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
       <div class="col-6 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
      <img src="assets/about/about1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
      <img src="assets/about/about2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
      <img src="assets/about/about3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-2 aboutMid aboutMid1">
      <img src="assets/about/about4.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```